# How to return boolean if calling object represents the same thing as the parameter?

Tags: java

So IPv4 addresses are passed, and if theyre the same IP, it should return true.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param other
 * @return true if calling object and parameter object represent 
 * the same ip address, and false otherwise
 */
public boolean equals(IPAddress other) {
    if(this.parts.equals(other.parts)){    //need help here
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
```

However, no matter which way I write the above, JUnit test cases

```
    public void testEqualsIPAddress() {
    correct1 = new IPAddress("0000192.168.1.0000254");
    correct2 = new IPAddress("255.000255.00000255.255");
    correct3 = new IPAddress("000.00.00.0000000000000");
    correct4 = new IPAddress("192.168.1.254");

    assertTrue(correct1.equals(correct4));
    assertTrue(correct4.equals(correct1));
    assertFalse(correct1.equals(correct3));
    assertFalse(correct2.equals(correct4));
}
```

return failures at

```
assertTrue(correct1.equals(correct4));
```

How should

```
 public boolean equals(IPAddress other){
//code here
}
```

be written?

Edit:

Here is the constructor

```
public class IPAddress {
    private int[] parts;
```

Comment: How can we guide you in what you're doing wrong, when you don't show us what the `IPAddress` constructor does, or what `parts` is? --- Also, keep in mind that `equals(IPAddress other)` is *not* an implementation of the `equals(Object)` method inherited from `Object`.

Comment: What is the type of  `correct1` ect? If it's not `IPAdress`, it won't work. Furthermore you haven't shown the constructor of `IPAddress`, so it could also contain a issue...

Comment: @fabian - If it were anything other than `IPAddress` (or a superclass), then it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Andreas I have added the constructor. ---- So how would one correctly implement     'equals(IPAddress other)'    ?

Comment: 1) That's not a constructor. --- 2) Java arrays don't implement `equals()`, which is why `this.parts.equals(other.parts)` doesn't work. You can call [`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a nested loop and return true if all parts are the same

```
public boolean equals(IPAddress other) {
if(this.parts[0] == other.parts[0])
    if(this.parts[1] == other.parts[1])
        if(this.parts[2] == other.parts[2])
            if(this.parts[3] == other.parts[3])
                return true;
return false;
}
```